# How do auto arguments work internally?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, auto

Consider the code,

```
#include <cstdio>

auto f(const auto &loc){
  printf("Location: %p\n", &loc);
}

int main()
{
  auto x {1};
  auto y {2.3};
  f(x);
  f(y);
}
```

compile with `g++ -std=c++14 dummy.cpp`

**Question:**

For template functions, the type is explicitly mentioned(`f<int>(2)`) at compile time.

How does the function `f` accept arguments of different type?

Comment: Everything is known at compile time here. So what is the question?

Comment: "For template functions, the type is explicitly mentioned" - not necessarily.  Function template calls can often deduce the template parameters from the function arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the [Concept Technical Specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) the 'function'

```
auto f(const auto &loc){
  printf("Location: %p\n", &loc);
}
```

is in fact a `template` (abbreviated function template declaration) and is equivalent to (but shorter and easier to read than)

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T&loc){
  printf("Location: %p\n", &loc);
}
```

Note, however, that the form using `auto` is not as of yet part of any C++ standard, but only of the [Concept Technical Specification](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) for concepts and constraints, which looks very powerful (but AFAIK is only supported by GNU's gcc version ≥6.1  with option `-fconcepts`).

Comment: If it is equivalent to `template` syntax, then, Is there any recommendation to prefer any one syntax?

Comment: If it is equivalent to `template` syntax, then which syntax is preferred(recommended)?

Comment: @overexchange: The recommendation is to prefer *standard* C++. And until Concepts become standard, that syntax is *not* legal C++.

Comment: @NicolBolas C++ style guide allows this syntax, [here](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-logical)

Comment: @overexchange: I can't control what things they put in there. I can only state *facts*. And the *facts* are that `auto` parameters for non-lambdas are not part of any C++ version up to and *including* C++17. That exists only in the Concepts TS, which is *not* part of the C++ standard. If Stroustrup wants to tell people to rely on non-standard compiler extensions, that's up to him and the users who follow that advice. It should also be noted that the page you linked to did not claim using this as a guideline; it was merely a suggestion.

Comment: @NicolBolas Can you provide document reference on standard C++?

Comment: @overexchange: I don't really know what you want from me. [The C++ standard](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) is the only "document reference on standard C++", but you could have found that by Googling "C++ standard". It's also a technical standard, not a learning document.

Comment: @NicolBolas: While the Concepts TS is not part of the C++ _standard_, it is part of the C++ _standards_ (plural). It is an official ISO Technical Specification (hence the TS), namely ISO/IEC TS 19217:2015. It's a bit more than a "proposal", the TS is published.